# How to search a string that the have ":" at the beginning with grep in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

I'm getting the number of appearances of a specific string in a file with:

```
grep -o "\bstring \b" $file | wc -l
```

But when I have a string like  ":2_n"  this string has ":" at the beginning and in this case grep doesn't work, it gives me a count of 0 each time even though my file has multiples ":2_n"
How can I do this?
Thankyou.

My file is like this

```
:2_n nE Ea an no o:2 :2_n _na
```

If I use grep to see the number appearances of ":2_n"

```
grep -o "\b:2_n \b" $file | wc -l
```

grep gives me 0, With other strings it works perfectly, the problem is with the strings that have ":" at the beginning

Comment: Since you have not shown samples so I couldn't test it in `grep`, if you are ok with `awk` could you please try following once `awk '{sum+=gsub(/:2_n/,"&")} END{print sum}' Input_file`?

Comment: Try with "grep -F "\bstring \b" $file | wc -l

Comment: `:2_n` doesn't match with `:2_n ` (white space just after).

Comment: Try `"string"`? Finding occurence of a *string* is sufficient.

Comment: I just update my question with an example, my string ":2_n" has a space just after.

Comment: `\b` matches a word boundary, which means character on left is word and character on right is non-word, or vice versa. `:` and beginning of line are both non-word, so `:` is not at a word boundary.

Comment: The obvious fix is to not look for a word boundary before the `:`.  Why can't you just remove that initiial `\b`?

Comment: that was a dumb mistake, removing the initial /b fixed it, thank you so much Toby and Barmar

Comment: @MaulikSakhida That would look for the literal string `\b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Barmar explains, the expression `\b` matches at the boundary between
a *word* character (alphanumeric plus "_") and a *non-word* character
(other characters than "word").

As the string `:2_n` starts with a non-word character and ends with a word
character, it is not suitable to use `\b` to extract the string out of the
sentence.
Let's see examples.

```
^:2_n    ("^" indicates the start of line)
 | Both "^" and ":" are non-word characters hence "\b" doesn't match.

:2_n :2_n
     | Both " " and ":" are non-word characters hence "\b" doesn't match.
```

Assuming your *string* is defined as *a sequence of non-blank character(s),
separated by a blank character*, you can say instead:

```
grep -Po "(^|(?<=\s)):2_n((?=\s|$))" file | wc -l
```

- The `-P` option to `grep` enables the perl-compatible regex.
- The pattern `(^|(?<=\s))` is a zero-width lookbehind assertion and
  matches the start of line or a preceding blank character without including
  it in in the result.
- The pattern `((?=\s|$))` is a zero-width lookahead assertion and
  matches the end of line or a following blank character without including
  it in in the result.

The `-P` option may not be supported depending the `grep` version.
Please let me know in such a case.

Comment: The -P option worked but is very slow

Comment: Then please try `ripgrep` instead. It is much faster than `grep`.